# React router returning the same element

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router to display some pages

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
     <Routes>
     <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
     <Route  path ="about" component={<AboutPage />}  />
     </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

But the second path is either display a blanck page in abouve piece of code or display the same homepage if i use like below

```
<Routes>
     <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} >
     <Route path ="about" component={<AboutPage />}  />
     </Route>
     </Routes>

</Router>
```

Which is the correct method to use to get the different pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second path still needs to be rendered on the `element` prop. In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` components no longer have `component`, and `render` and `children` function props, they were replaced by the single `element` prop taking a `ReactElement`.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
     <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
       <Route path="about" element={<AboutPage />} />
     </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```